# Unable to Hit HTTP Port with RequestBuilder In GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using the `sendRequest()` method of `RequestBuilder` in GWT.  I am using Eclipse Indigo, JRE 1.7 and GWT 2.5.0.

My problem is that I am not able to hit the specified HTTP port with the `sendRequest()` method.  I have used the same code on another machine and it worked.  I have switched off my firewall but still it is still not working on my machine.

Comment: When you say you are "not able to hit the specified HTTP port" what do you mean? Are you getting a `RequestException`? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: Please show some codes or stackTrace.Otherwise its hard to find where exactly the problem

Comment: No, there is no RequestException that I am getting.
But the HttpReceiver that is listening on the port, does not get the JSON Object values that i am sending through the sendRequest() method.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `sendRequest()` uses `XMLHttpRequest`, so by default you can only hit the same server and http port than you are using for your html page.

So check that the url in your browser is exactly the same than you set in your `RequestBuilder`.

If you want to do CORS from gwt, you can read this  [page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax) (focus on JSONP and CORS sections), or any of the pages around Internet talking about CORS.

Monitoring the net traffic in FireBug could help, if you try to access other servers you should see OPTION requests apart from GET or POST.

Comment: ERROR : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@180634b
 ERROR : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1f6f9b3
ERROR : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@11eab62
this is the response on my Console

Comment: with this info I cannot help you have to compile with PRETTY option or  emulated compiler.stackMode , what is the info in the network traffic?